# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'exists Sync' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, file-upload, firebase-authentication, imagepicker

```
 Future uploadFile() async {
    String fileName = DateTime.now().toString();
    StorageReference reference =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('$fileName');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl) {
      setState(() {
        imageUrl = downloadUrl;
        print("image path===>" + imageUrl);
      });
    }, onError: (err) {
      setState(() {});
      toast(text: thisFileNotInImage);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `putFile` return a `Future`, so do something like this,

```
StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask()
```

and we don't need `await` when using `.then`, here

```
await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then
```

Refer: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Answer (score 0):

It appears your `image` variable is null. Ensure your image is not null before passing it into the `Reference.putFile()` method.

The error is appearing from this line:

```dart
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(image);
```

Check out the implementation of `Reference.putFile()` below. The error appears to come from the assertion.

```dart
    UploadTask putFile(File file, [SettableMetadata? metadata]) {
      assert(file.absolute.existsSync());
      return UploadTask._(storage, _delegate.putFile(file, metadata));
    }
```